# Is there any practical SPICE modeling of a DC behavior of a diode from its given limited specs?

Tags: diodes, spice

I have a laser diode and its shared electrical data is limited comparing to other diode datasheets. It has a V-I curve below(dashed red one):

[image]

And three other parameters:

[image]

(Reverse saturation current is not given)

I couldnt find any calculator/tool/site that estimates Rs, N and Is from given I-V points.

Comment: Good answer here that might help:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/how-do-i-model-an-led-with-spice/9543#9543

Answer (score 1):

Rs: is the slope in the high current region.

Is: for  a LED assume something small like 1e-15.

Then tune N until you are happy with the agreement.

Comment: Isnt Rs ohmic resistance and it is constant? When you say slope, it reminds me dynamic resistance which is not constant.

Comment: @cm64 look how the IV curve assumes a constant slope (equal to Rs) up in the high current region. That is because the dynamic resistance of the junction becomes too low to matter..So the net resistance reduces to the ohmic resistance of the diode.